# Get expansion of Wikivoyage articles in chat...please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks

When we post Wikipedia articles in chat it expands into a preview.

It'd be really handy if we could get that for [Wikivoyage](http://www.wikivoyage.org/) articles as well....we refer to it a LOT.

Comment: Yes this should be trivial to implement. No coding should be required, just a bit of configuring.

Comment: @hippietrail: 6 to 8 weeks, tops :-)

Comment: We got it last time we asked for WikiTravel: [We would like Wikitravel links to auto-expand in our chat room just like Wikipedia links do.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/396)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I simply didn't notice this one until Mark Mayo's comment on the previous request. Done and done.

Comment: legend! Thanks for that.